# To pass collection to Stored procedure call as input without using the variable

Tags: oracle, collections, user-input, procedure

I have a requirement where we have to call a oracle Stored Procedure which has collection type as input parameter.
So my stored procedure is like:

```
Create or replace package test
As 

Type t is table of varchar(400) index by binary_integer.

Procedure testprc(p_client_id in number,t_no in number,t1 in t,t2 in t);

End;

Create or replace package body test
As

Procedure testprc(p_client_id in number,t_no in number,t1 in t, t2 in t)
is

Begin

for i in 1 ..tno loop

Insert into client
(Client_id,Client_phone,client_email) values (p_client_id,t1(i),t2(i));

End loop;

End;

End;
```

Now in the call to this stored procedure testprc.test I don't want to create a variable of type t and pass it to the stored procedure instead I want to directly pass the list of values to the SP.
Something like this

```
Exec testprc(13,1,{1=>'22737371'},{1=>'test@abc.com'}).
```

Is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that without concatenating a big long ugly string and then parsing it in the proc, which is not a good design. You should try to assemble a real collection object in your calling client/routine and pass it as a collection.

Comment: Would be like this: `Exec testprc(13, 1 ,t('2737371', 'test@abc.com'), t('test'));` or `Exec testprc(p_client_id  => 13, t_no => 1, t1 => t('2737371', 'test@abc.com'), t2 => t('test'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 18c or higher, you can use a qualified expression to avoid having to create a temporary variable to hold associative arrays. For example:

```
SQL> exec test.testprc(13,1,test.t(1=>'22737371'),test.t(1=>'test@abc.com'))

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```